# how to use java code in xamarin.android?

Tags: java, dll, jar, xamarin.android, barcode

I have to use RFID scanner library that is in java in my xamarin.android application.

> first of all i extracted .jar file from .aar file.
>
> then i created binding library(.DLL) from that .jar file.and included
>   in my xamarin.andorid project.

when i double click .DLL file i can see some of java classes in that.it might converted automatically.

I have help development document for that product in java code.

how can I use that or convert that for my .ddl

as I have no knowledge of java at all.plus i dont get all classes of .jar file in my .DLL

I coudnt find any code sample regarding  xamarin.android.

I might not clearly asked question.so sorry for that.

but please help if anyone have idea about this.

it will be great help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you go through [Going From Java to C# Development](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/xamarin-for-java/#Going_From_Java_to_C_Development) first.

Then regarding your questions, you need to follow the official documentations:

> how can I use that or convert that for my .ddl
>
> as I have no knowledge of java at all.plus i dont get all classes of .jar file in my .DLL

You can refer to the [Binding Java Library Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/).

> I coudnt find any code sample regarding xamarin.android.

The official samples for Xamarin.Android in Github: [monodroid-samples](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples).